# time.time() is not working when it mentioned as args

Tags: python, class, time, arguments

I'm trying to make instance by the code as below

but I found that time() is not working well when it belong to args.
I don't know why TT

```
from time import time
class fourcal:
  def setda(self, a, b,t = time()):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.t = time()
    print(t)
    print(self.t)
```

you can found that result by `print(t)` is same for two instance.

[image]

Comment: Default arguments are only evaluated *once*.

Comment: @deceze when it evaluate ? compile or create class ? Do you have any recommend ?

Comment: I recommend you read the duplicate above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416002/476